# text and image next to each other inside background div

Tags: html, css

i'm not really good with css... maybe someone can help me..

I'm trying to put text next to my jquery image slider... i cant figure it out.

slider_bg is just the background image...i should probably remove this div and combine it with one of my others...

html:

```
          <div class="slider_bg">
          <div id="caption">MY CAPTION TEXT LEFT OF IMAGE
           <div id="banner-fade">
            <ul class="bjqs">
            <li><img src="images/img1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="images/img3.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

css:

```
#banner-fade {
display: block;
right:-358px;
top:17px;
margin-left:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;
padding:1px;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

#caption {
    top: 1px;
    left: 2px;
    }

.slider_bg {
width:100%;
height:404px;
background:url(../images/bg_bot.jpg) top center repeat;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
margin-bottom:35px;
}
```

when i do it this way, its showing the text on the left..but the image is then not aligned properly like how i would like it on the right side... close to right side border and centered top/bottom.

Comment: Add 'display: inline-block;' to both of the elements

Comment: Do you mean you want it on the same height as the text? Then just use float: right on the image

Comment: i tried inline-block and float .. not working

Comment: It's not clear what you're attempting to do here. Can you make a JSFiddle & include your JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `float:left` and `float:right` you have to add your text in a `div` and make it `float:left` and your `#banner-fade` `float:right`

But `display:inline-block` should work with this as it is

check [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/mf2JY/1/)